# cgo call C function with void**

Tags: go, cgo

I have a function using a `void **` parameter which I have to call form Go. How can this be called or wrapped?

```golang
/*
static int create_key_pair(void** key) {
}
*/
import "C"

func CreateKey() {
// how to call this function?
    C.create_key_pair(???)
}
```

I tried:

```golang
func CreateKey() {
    var prk uintptr
    C.create_key_pair(unsafe.Pointer(&prk))
}
```

but then I get:

> cannot use _cgo0 (variable of type unsafe.Pointer) as type *unsafe.Pointer in argument to _Cfunc_create_key_pair

Comment: `void**` is a pointer to a pointer, but `uintptr` is a pointer sized integer, not a pointer. Try `*unsafe.Pointer` like the error says

Comment: @JimB How does this work? A reference to unsafe.Pointer cannot be made, i.e. `&unsafe.Pointer(...)` is not possible

Comment: @JimB OK, with the intermediate it works. At least it compiles. Let's what it gives at compile time. You could also write this as answer.